# Create curved grid lines in QGIS Map Composer

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, print-composer

I would like to create a "traditional map" in QGIS that looks like this:

[image]

So I would like to have a grid, that is bent/curved visible on the Map with the coordinate-degrees at the side. My Projection system is UTM 33N WGS84 (EPSG 32633).

But when I create the Grid in the Map composer of QGIS. The lines are always straight, but not bent like on the topographical map I posted the link from...

How can I create such a "traditional" map with curved lines and the correct degrees in a grid that has 250 km x 250 km?

Comment: UTM coordinate system was created so the grid wouldn't be bended in the graphical representation. That's the point of that system. Check for example this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOwfn.jpg and this (with degrees): https://www.maptools.com/images/2461fb1.png . If you want it to be bended, you would need to pick a different one.

Comment: Security is not the only reason to avoid outside links. Question has to be complete in itself and include all relevant code and images, since outside links tend to get lost in time and also that there is no need to visit other sites to get complete picture of what the problem/question is.

Comment: You'd need to use a conic projection to get curved parallels with meridians converging toward the pole. Albers Equal Area or Lambert Conformal Conic might suit, but UTM won't. You should research the projection actually used in your "traditional" map, then use that.